# Окончание "-е" или "-и" в существительном

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, существительные

Объясните, пожалуйста, правило, а также более подробно ситуацию написания.

*Эта девушка выйдет на следующей остановк**е**.*
Почему в слове "остановке" окончание -Е, а не -И?

Comment: Правило указано в таблице окончаний склонений существительных.

Comment: Здесь падеж предложный. О маме, на крыше,  на траве.

Answer (score 1):

Оно соответствует типу окончания данного слова в именительном падеже (остановк**а**). Окончание -**и** было бы напр. в случае *на следующей пристан**и*** (пристан**ь**, ж. р.).